# Android resource linking failed datetimepicker attrs not found

Tags: android, xml, build, build.gradle

there is a ton of questions pertaining to this type of exception an i really dont get how it came about. I guess the exception is telling me that there are a bunch of date picker attributes that it expected to find in the styles file of my app that it could not find and I do not understand why as I swear exactly the same code was compiling flawlessly a few months back. What I dont inderstand is why its even looking for those in my project folder all those attrs are actually found and well defined on the values file where the exception stems from. all suggestions such as cleaning and rebuilding or upgrading to androidx have not worked. this is so vexing

```
AAPT: C:\Users\theo\Desktop\GymLog_App\GymLogMulti\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeGenericVersionDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:3535: error: style attribute 'attr/minDate (aka com.example.android.gymlogmulti.generic:attr/minDate)' not found.
C:\Users\theo\Desktop\GymLog_App\GymLogMulti\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeGenericVersionDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:3536: error: style attribute 'attr/maxDate (aka com.example.android.gymlogmulti.generic:attr/maxDate)' not found.
C:\Users\theo\Desktop\GymLog_App\GymLogMulti\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeGenericVersionDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:3544: error: style attribute 'attr/weekDayTextAppearance (aka com.example.android.gymlogmulti.generic:attr/weekDayTextAppearance)' not found.
C:\Users\theo\Desktop\GymLog_App\GymLogMulti\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeGenericVersionDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:3545: error: style attribute 'attr/dateTextAppearance (aka com.example.android.gymlogmulti.generic:attr/dateTextAppearance)' not found.
C:\Users\theo\Desktop\GymLog_App\GymLogMulti\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeGenericVersionDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:3551: error: style attribute 'attr/datePickerMode (aka com.example.android.gymlogmulti.generic:attr/datePickerMode)' not found.
C:\Users\theo\Desktop\GymLog_App\GymLogMulti\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeGenericVersionDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:3552: error: style attribute 'attr/dtp_legacyLayout (aka com.example.android.gymlogmulti.generic:attr/dtp_legacyLayout)' not found.
C:\Users\theo\Desktop\GymLog_App\GymLogMulti\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeGenericVersionDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:3553: error: style attribute 'attr/calendarViewShown (aka com.example.android.gymlogmulti.generic:attr/calendarViewShown)' not found.
C:\Users\theo\Desktop\GymLog_App\GymLogMulti\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeGenericVersionDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:3638: error: style attribute 'attr/weekDayTextAppearance (aka com.example.android.gymlogmulti.generic:attr/weekDayTextAppearance)' not found.
C:\Users\theo\Desktop\GymLog_App\GymLogMulti\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeGenericVersionDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:3639: error: style attribute 'attr/dateTextAppearance (aka com.example.android.gymlogmulti.generic:attr/dateTextAppearance)' not found.
C:\Users\theo\Desktop\GymLog_App\GymLogMulti\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeGenericVersionDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:3644: error: style attribute 'attr/datePickerMode (aka com.example.android.gymlogmulti.generic:attr/datePickerMode)' not found.
```

Comment: Did you change the target version/min version of Android? Did you update your Gradle dependencies? This could lead to heavy errors. You may also paste the important parts of you values.xml

Comment: gradle updated itself that was where the issue started. then i did in fact change a bunch of parameters in the gradle files and even migrated to androidx but only in order to fix the issue that was already there. at the end it seems like there were conflicting attributes in a third party dependency. ditching this dependency solved it

Answer (score 1):

I just found the source of the issue by using CTRL+SHIFT+F and looking for the problematic attributes in the code (of the entire scope). Turns out the culprit was a third party dependency. Once i uninstalled it it was fixed. I guess the issue came from updating gradle and these outdated libraries somehow interfering with it.
I still dont understand the nature of the issue exactly but I hope this helps someone else dealing with the same issue. I just spent waaay to long looking at this.